# How was the law of total probability used here for this conditional probability to get this result?

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

If $X(t)$ is observed at a random time $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$, then, by the law of total probability, we have that
$$P(X(U) = k \mid X(0) = 1) = \int_0^\infty P(X(u) = k \mid X(0) = 1) g_U(u) \ du,$$

where

$$g_U(u) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 < u < 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

How was the law of total probability used here for this conditional probability to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I will ignore the conditioning on $X(0)=1$ in my answer for simplicity; you can apply the same argument with conditioning on $X(0)=1$ afterward.]

General result:
If $X = (X(t))_t$ and $U$ are independent and if $U$ has a density $g_U$, then $E[f(X,U) \mid U=u] = E[f(X, u)]$ and thus
$$E[f(X,U)] = E[E[f(X,U) \mid U]] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty E[f(X,u)] g_U(u) \, du.$$

Applying this with $f(x,u) := \mathbf{1}_{x(u)=k}$ gives
$$P(X(U)=k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X(u)=k) g_U(u) \, du.$$

---

You can modify this to condition on some other event $A$ that is independent of $U$. The general result would become $E[f(X,U) \mid U=u, A]  = E[f(X,u) \mid A]$, and
$$E[f(X,U) \mid A] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty E[f(X,u) \mid A] g_U(u) \, du.$$

Comment: But if you ignore the $X(0) = 1$, then you’re ignoring the entire point of my question, are you not? The point was that I wanted to see how it would work for a conditional probability, but what you’ve shown is just for the non-conditional case, no?

Comment: @ThePointer Not really, see my edit.

Comment: I don't understand why this has expected values in it. For instance, there are no expected values in the Wikipedia definition of law of total probability for continuous random variables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case

Comment: @ThePointer I'm using the law of total expectation (which is more general than the law of total probability). If you want to generalize the law of total probability as written on Wikipedia, you can condition everything on an event $B$ that is independent of $X$ to obtain $P(A \mid B) = \int P(A \mid B, X=x) f_X(x) \, dx$.

Comment: Ok, putting it that way makes more sense to me.